# AWS signed cookies authentication not working php (AccessDeniedAccess denied)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to access static content from my s3 bucket using AWS CloudFront. I am able to access that content using signed URL but when I am trying to use AWS signed cookies authentication it is giving me **AccessDeniedAccess denied** error.
I have double check my CloudFront and S3 bucket configuration. But it seems perfect. 
I am using Custom SSL certificate for my CloudFront and canned policy to access the content.

```
<?php
getSignature("http://cdn.******.ca", 300000);
echo '<html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <iframe src="https://cdn.****/file.pdf">
      </body>
      </html>';

function getSignature($resource = null, $expires = null, $policy = null)
    {

        $keyPairId = 'AP*****';

        $signatureHash = array();
         if ($policy) {
            $policy = preg_replace('/\s/s', '', $policy);
            $signatureHash['Policy'] = encode($policy);
            header ( "Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Policy=".$signatureHash['Policy']."; path=/; domain=***.ca; httpOnly", false );
            } 
         elseif ($resource && $expires) {
            $policy = createCannedPolicy($resource, $expires);
            $signatureHash['Expires'] = $expires;
            header ( "Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Expires=".$signatureHash['Expires']."; path=/; domain=***.ca; httpOnly", false );
            }
         else {
           return false;
        }

        $signatureHash['Signature'] = encode(sign($policy));
        header ( "Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Signature=".$signatureHash['Signature']."; path=/; domain=***.ca; httpOnly", false );
        $signatureHash['Key-Pair-Id'] = $keyPairId;
        header ( "Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=".$signatureHash['Key-Pair-Id']."; path=/; domain=***.ca; httpOnly", false );

        return $signatureHash;
    }

    function createCannedPolicy($resource, $expiration)
    {
        $json = '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"'.$resource.'","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":'.$expiration.'}}}]}';
        return $json;
    }

    function sign($policy)
    {
    $signature = '';
        $privateKey = 'path/pk-APK***.pem';
        $fp=fopen($privateKey,"r");
        $priv_key=fread($fp,8192);
        fclose($fp);

        $key = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);
    openssl_sign($policy, $signature, $key);
        return $signature;
    }

    function encode($policy)
    {
        return strtr(base64_encode($policy), '+=/', '-_~');
    }
?>
```

Comment: When you send the request, is your browser actually sending the cookies?

Comment: Yes, it does. I can see cookies on my browser and it is sending the cookies.

Comment: You say you are using a canned policy? That doesn't usually make sense with signed cookies.

Comment: I also have tried with custom policy but error remains the same